# React Native Packager package.json "browser" field

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make our JavaScript [library](https://github.com/getstream/stream-js) compatible with React Native. Currently the package supports both the browser and nodejs environments through the use of the "browser" field in our package.json. As far as I am aware the React Native Packager should also adhere to the spec of this field, but somehow when I install the package in a React Native project and run the packager it fails on requiring the "url" package (which is shimmed through the browser field).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a react-native field in your package.json like so:

`"react-native": "./dist/index.js"`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found that only the "main" file can be replaced.